# Javascript if/else statement returns no output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript code (in an HTML document) returns no output. Without the `if`/`else`, it functions, but even a simple `if` does not work.

Goal: Find out HTML input value's modulus, and return even if 0 and odd if anything else.

Code(s):

HTML Input + Button:

```
<input id="num" type="number" min="1" name="num">
      <button onclick="calculate(); evenodd();  return false;">Go</button>
```

(The `calculate()` is another JS function, which works perfectly)

HTML Output:

```
<p id="evod"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function evenodd () {


        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);


        if (num2 % 2) == 0) {
          document.getElementById("evod").innerHTML = "Even"; 
            }

        else {
          document.getElementById("evod").innerHTML = "Odd";
            }

      }

     </script type="text/javascript">
     </script>
```

Comment: does `evenodd()` even run? Try a console.log maybe? You've got another function there called `calculate()`, and if that doesn't exist (which, according to the code you provided, it doesn't), I don't think the next function would execute.

Comment: Keep your browser developer console open. The first thing to do when your JavaScript code doesn't work is check for errors in the console!

Comment: You've tagged this with jquery but then not used even the most basic jquery - please remove the tag or confirm it's ok to be removed.

Comment: You're parsing your input in *base 8* - I assume this is unintended... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @sg.cc `calculate()` exists, just  that I did not provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a syntax error:

```
if (num2 % 2) == 0) {
```

You're missing the opening parenthesis immediately before `num2` as so:

```
if ((num2 % 2) == 0) {
```

Also, you have malformed HTML. You're script should be formatted as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JS code
</script>
```

You should never have attributes in a closing tag.

To debug this yourself, try opening the developer console in your browser (Ctrl+Shift+J or F12 will get you there in most cases) and see what errors are being reported.